# I am not getting option for dumb node in manage nodes option in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am using jenkins 2.7.2 and I am not getting option for dumb node in manage nodes option in Jenkins. I want to know which plugin is missing for that option.

Comment: We need an MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

There are different plugins for different kind of slaves. For dumb node slave, windows_slave plugin is needed. 
You can download that plugin from the following link :
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Windows+Slaves+Plugin